# Request Validation - ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0, request-validation

Has request validation changed for ASP.NET MVC 2, more precisely, not validating?

I did the following:

Web.configs (in App directory and Views directory)

```
<pages
    validateRequest="false"
```

Controller/Action Attribute

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

In @Page View Directive

```
ValidateRequest="false"
```

The page still gets validated an exception is thrown when HTML content is posted.

UPDATE

Created a new ASP.NET MVC 2 Application and I modified the Home Controller's Index to this

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Index(string InputText)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }
```

and my View Page

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm()){ %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("InputText") %>
    <input type="submit" />
<% } %>
```

And still the same issue, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I should read the error more carefully next time:

> To allow pages to override application request validation settings, 
>   set requestValidationMode="2.0" in the configuration section. 
>   After setting this value, you can then disable request validation by 
>   setting validateRequest="false"

I put this in the application's web.config

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
</system.web>
```

and it worked.

Update:

I was running ASP.NET 4 thats why :P

Comment: Inside the `<system.web>` begin/end tags

Comment: this did not work for me, I had to use the attributes for MVC2 RTM

Comment: @Alexandre Brisebois, odd are you using .NET 4?

Comment: yes, but thinking of it, it's on a project that was upgraded by VS 2010

Comment: I misunderstood your first comment. You have to use attributes AND this setting in your Web.config file for it to work in .NET 4

Comment: If you're using MVC4, you need to add this to the `web.config` in the `Views` directory, it didn't work for me when placed into the root `web.config`  HTH  :o)

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Insert obligatory warning about XSS here.*</sup>

That you decorated the controller (or action) with the `ValidateInputAttribute` should be enough, as all validation is done at this controller level in ASP.NET MVC

I have just tried this now on an action, and it returns a nice, evil alert() when I output it, so I'd venture a guess that there's something else going on here.

Do you have an `HandleErrorAttribute` set up anywhere?

Comment: I implemented a custom viewpage you can see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480373/generic-inhertied-viewpage-and-new-property , looking to see if anything is causing it to validate with ASP.NET MVC 2

Comment: No HandleError attribute too.