# ValidateInputAttribute bug in VS 2010 RC / ASP.NET MVC 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Am I doing something wrong here?

I have a text area on a view and am posting back the html contents. In VS 2008 and MVC 1.0 the following code successfully prevents input validation:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    return View();
}
```

If I execute this code in VS 2010 / MVC 2.0 I always get this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (body="
> ").

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: [Request Validation - ASP.NET MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648386/request-validation-asp-net-mvc-2)

Try adding this to your page directive:

```
ValidateRequest="false"
```

Comment: The <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/> attribute works if you are targeting .net 4, but I am targeting 3.5 so am unable to add this attribute to web.config.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work still. Perhaps it just the combination of targeting asp.net 3.5 with mvc 2.0?