# ASP.NET MVC generic base view class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net

I can have a base class for views in an MVC project like this:

```
public class BaseViewPage : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
{
  public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

And then in the ASPX I can do this:

```
<%@ Page Something="foo" Language="C#" Inherits="MyNamespace.BaseViewPage" %>
```

This works fine; the problem is when I try to do the same with the generic version:

```
public class BaseViewPage<TModel> : 
    System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TModel> where TModel : class
{
  public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to use this from the ASPX, like this:

```
<%@ Page Something="foo" Language="C#" 
    Inherits="MyNamespace.BaseViewPage<SomeClass>" %>
```

I get the error message:

> Error parsing attribute 'something': Type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage' does not have a public property named 'something'.

Notice how it tries to use System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage rather than my BaseViewPage class. To make it more interesting, if I remove the "Something" attribute from the Page directive and put some code in the generic version of BaseViewPage (OnInit for example) the class is actually called / used / instantiated.

So, am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation / bug? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic Inherited ViewPage<> and new Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480373/generic-inherited-viewpage-and-new-property)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this exact same question a few months ago. Drove me nuts until [Justin Grant answered it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480373/generic-inhertied-viewpage-and-new-property/1512027#1512027)

Comment: Very nice; thanks a lot! I tried to search SO before posting, but I guess I didn't use the right words...