# In ASP.NET MVC, why can't I inherit from "MyCustomView" without specifying the full type name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC apps I normally declare a base view type that all of my views inherit from. I get a parser error when I specify `Inherits="MyView"` in my Page declaration, but not if I specify `Inherits="MyApp.Web.Views.MyView"`.

Strangely enough, it **works fine if I specify a strongly typed view name**: `Inherits="MyView<T>` (where T is any valid type).

Why can I specify a strongly typed view without the full type name, but not a generic view?

My base view class is declared like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Web.Views {
    public class MyView : MyView<object> {
    }

    public class MyView<TModel> : ViewPage<TModel> where TModel : class {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Note that I *do* import MyApp.Web.Views via web.config. If I did not, then the strongly typed approach (`Inherits="MyView<T>"`) wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From another post: **Here's the underlying issue: the ASP.NET page parser does not support generics as a page type**

Read more here- [Generic Inherited ViewPage<> and new Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480373/generic-inhertied-viewpage-and-new-property)

Comment: Very interesting... I haven't read all of the code on that page yet, but it sounds like the issue I've reported is caused by some of the generic/non-generic juju that's being done behind the scenes. If I'm successful at using Justin's code to resolve my issue I'll post an update here.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your namespace to the `<namespaces>` element of your web.config file then you should be able to use `Inherits="MyView"`

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="MyApp.Web.Views" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: I _do_ import the namespace like this. Otherwise the strongly typed view [Inherits="MyView[ModelType]"] wouldn't work either.

Comment: @Seth: But, have you added the namespace in the web.config?