# Why can't I use C# Syntax in the Inherits Attribute for a Closed Generic but CLR Syntax is fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

The following CLR syntax works fine in my aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="Website.MyBasePage`1[HomePageViewModel]" %>
```

But this C# syntax does not:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="Website.MyBasePage<HomePageViewModel>" %>
```

Note, I am not using ASP.NET MVC, but this works fine if using `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<>` from ASP.NET MVC.

My `MyBasePage` looks like this:

```
public class MyBasePage<TModel> : Page where TModel : class {
    public TModel Model
    {
        get { return (TModel)HttpContext.Current.Items["model"]; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to know the exception you are getting but I would suspect that the problem is that having generic page base classes is not supported directly by ASP.net.  It is achieved in MVC using a bit of a hack.

You can repeat this hack yourself if you are using Web Forms,  this should help:

[Generic Inherited ViewPage<> and new Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480373/generic-inhertied-viewpage-and-new-property/1512027#1512027)

Comment: James - Thanks for the link. I think you pinpointed exactly what is going on. For the record the error I am getting is:
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Website.MyBasePage<HomeViewModel>'.