# Inherits Tag generates bad design.cs code with generic class

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, partial

In a asp.net control, when I try to do

```
Inherits="Maclasse<U,V>"
```

The code generates me :

```
public partial class Maclasse<U {
```

which gives an error.

I tried to escape with \ , to put inherits with simple quotes, nothing seems to work.

Have anybody an idea of how to solve this problem ?

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.Net parser doesn't support inheritance from a generic class. There is, however, a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1512027/291999

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the better solution for me was to recreate the IHM using code, so no problem with the asp.net webpage parser.

Of course i'm happy my component was quite simple, I would have been obliged to use the workaround otherwise.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, if it is know solved. This lets other people know your problem was solved.